# How can I output the full web-page specific content with Powershell wget?

Tags: windows, powershell, http, cmd, wget

When I issue the command `powershell.exe wget http://IP_ADDR:8080/config/version/` I get the response:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"Content of the web page does not fully show through this output… How can I use wget to just show the full content of the webpage without cutting it out?
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Content-Length: 307
                    Content-Type: application/json
                    Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 04:20:04 GMT
                    Server: CherryPy/3.2.2

                    {"Content of the web page does not fully show...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Content-Length, 307], [Content-Type, application/json], [Date, Wed, 26 Apr 2017 04:20:04 GMT],
                    [Server, CherryPy/3.2.2]}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 307
```

As above, the command shows only part of the content, and not the full output of what is returned when I go to the address normally.

My other alternative is to just use curL, but I would like a native resolution to the above other than a third-party tool.

My question is, how can I use the wget command to only show the output of the content, and the full output of it?

Comment: `(powershell.exe wget http://IP_ADDR:8080/config/version/).RawContent`

Comment: `powershell (wget http://IP_ADDR:8080/config/version/).Content` was the correct syntax; thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the comments, you need to access either the `.Content` or `.RawContent` property (RawContent contains the HTTP header fields where as Content does not. Note that the Headers are also available in the `.Headers` property):

```
powershell.exe (wget http://IP_ADDR:8080/config/version/).Content
```

or

```
powershell.exe (wget http://IP_ADDR:8080/config/version/).RawContent
```

To explain what is occurring, PowerShell returns Objects rather than plain text which to put simply means they are like mini databases with properties that can be returned/filtered etc. What you see when you make your call is the default view of a subset of properties of the object, which is not all of the properties available.

To learn more about wget look up `Invoke-WebRequest` which is the full cmdlet name (`wget` is an alias of it).

As a further aside, if your web call is returning JSON or XML you might want to consider using `Invoke-RestMethod` instead as that will take the JSON or XML and convert it automatically a PowerShell object (which you could then further manipulate within PowerShell).

Comment: The parenthesis starts after issuing powershell, otherwise this will not work inside CMD. `powershell (wget http://IP_ADDR:8080/config/version/).Content` is the correct syntax via Windows CMD. Thank you for the additional information.

Comment: Thanks, will amend.